# Can sockets in python be used without internet access

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to send data from one software to another running on the same pc. The coding in the former s/w is done in python. I'm doing this:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto("msg,Hi!", ("127.0.0.1", 12345))
```

This works fine when I have internet access (AF_INET). However, this is just a sample code and I will need to include this piece in some other application where I will not have internet access and so AF_INET wouldn't work. Is there a possible replacement for this?

I've already tried AF_UNIX and AF_LOCAL but neither of them works. I need to use UDP.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?  What happens when you `ping 127.0.0.1` when the internet is not connected?

Answer (score 4):

AF_INET has nothing to do with the INTERNET. It just means use IP based communication. You can do it on the same computer or across computers. 127.0.0.1 refers to local-host IP i.e. my own IP. Each unix/linux machine has the same local IP.

So yes this code will work without internet access.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have been trying this without internet. I can see the message on the other application only when my laptop is connected to the internet. Without internet, though I don't get any error, I don't see the message on the other app. Can you please suggest some other way for this?

Comment: Is the other application "listening" on 127.0.0.1 ? Or only on a specific IP ? Please run "netstat -plnu"

Comment: It is listening. I know this because I can send data from my phone to that application on that ip and port. The app receives data from my phone with and without internet. But when i try the same thing from my first s/w, it doesn't work without internet

Comment: Disconnect internet and do a tcpdump -i lo -nevvv

Answer (score 0):

Of course, You do not need any Internet concepts while using Sockets. You can use an ad-hoc network to create a relaxed network and run a simple **TCP** or **UDP** socket script to transfer things you like.

You can infact use **Multicasting** or **Broadcasting** schemes to share data on different devices within the ad-hoc network.